# UILabel have a weird grey top line/border in iOS7, how can I remove it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a basic UILabel that I use in a `UITableViewCell`. I'm experiencing some strange behaviour, on some cells (not all) the UILabel gets a grey top border, see picture below. And I'm not sure how to fix it.

[image]

I create my UILabel like this:

```
if (self.postText == nil) {
    CGRect postTextRect = CGRectMake(self.profileImage.frame.origin.x + self.profileImage.frame.size.width + 5, self.username.frame.origin.y + self.username.frame.size.height, frame.size.width - self.profileImage.frame.size.width - self.profileImage.frame.origin.y -10, self.frame.size.height - self.username.frame.size.height - self.username.frame.origin.y + 40);
    self.postText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:postTextRect];
    self.postText.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.postText.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    self.postText.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.postText.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.postText];
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Update**

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks like this:

```
- (id)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [...]
    static NSString *postCellIdentifier = @"PostCell";
    PostCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:postCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PostCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:postCellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath forPost:cellPost];
    return cell;
}
```

And the relevant par of `configureCell` like this:

```
- (void)configureCell:(PostCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forPost:(Post *)post
{
    [...]

    cell.username.text = cellUser.username;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(cell.postText.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [cell.postText.text sizeWithFont:cell.postText.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGRect newFrame = cell.postText.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    cell.postText.frame = newFrame;

    CGRect containerRect = CGRectMake(5, 5, cell.containerView.frame.size.width, cell.postText.frame.size.height + cell.username.frame.origin.y + cell.username.frame.size.height + 10);
    if (containerRect.size.height < 65) {
        containerRect.size.height = 65;
    }

    cell.containerView.frame = containerRect;
    [...] 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the BG color to clear ?

Comment: @AleksanderAzizi, yes, and it didn't help.

Comment: have you tried to remove uitableviewcell separator?

Comment: @Ilario Yes, didn't help either.

Comment: this cell that have this line, have something in particular?

Comment: @Ilario, not what I can think of. Seems to be quite random. Which makes it more difficult. ~40% of the cells have it.

Comment: random? first time for example the third cell has line, and second time the second cell has line? this mean?

Comment: @Ilario No, not like that. The line stays on the same cells. But I can't find anything special about the cells other then the line.

Comment: can you post cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: why don't you set the `backgroundColor` of `UILabel` to `clearColor` and its actual superview could be white...

Comment: @Anders, Consider accepting a solution.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by rounding up the height:

```
newFrame.size.height = ceilf(expectedLabelSize.height);
```

Comment: For Swift: ceil(expectedLabelSize.height)

Comment: You can also use `cell.containerView.frame = CGRectIntegral(containerRect)`.

Answer (score 4):

Got the same issue

Solved by assigning border color and width to UILabel

`nameLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
nameLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;`

Answer (score 4):

It must be a iOS's bug. The bug is triggered by the float height value of the label. So, the easy and no side-effect way to solve it is converting the float height value to int value:

```
(int)(label.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 1):

Decided to use a `UITextView` instead.

The problem seems to occur when changing the UILabel's frame.

Chaning this code:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(cell.postText.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [cell.postText.text sizeWithFont:cell.postText.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
CGRect newFrame = cell.postText.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
cell.postText.frame = newFrame;
```

to...

```
[cell.postText sizeToFit];
```

Did remove the border. But the content wasn't displayed just as I wanted it, that's why I changed to `UITextView`

Answer (score 1):

The weird grey outlines is due to the background size and label size is not exact the same.

It can be solved perfectly by:

```
[myLabel sizeToFit]
```

Answer (score 0):

The real reason is your frame height or width is not integer or change your app view` background color to clear color.

把frame的width 或者height修改为整数，或者设置背景色为clear color 即可.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        cell.postText.layer.borderColor = self.Detail.backgroundColor.CGColor;
        cell.postText.layer.borderWidth = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seem that the problem appears when you change the frame property of the label, setting width or height with float value.

This solution works for me, setting the backgroundColor of the label to Clear.

Objective-C:

```
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

swift:

```
label.setBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. just doing `labelView.layer.opaque = false;` fixed mine. hope this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem in a .xib that was partially implemented with Auto Layout and partially implemented with Translates Mask Into Constraints. Once I converted it to full Auto Layout, the problem went away even though the sizes still had some half-points.